# Stripe 'card' not defined

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am following this tutorial: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price. They never instantiate a variable called card, which leads me to believe that card is a stripe component that comes with `"https://js.stripe.com/v3/"`. When I run the frontend, I get the following error: `payment_portal:214 Uncaught ReferenceError: card is not defined`. The error occurs in this codeblock, right here `createPaymentMethod({ card });`:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  
  // If a previous payment was attempted, get the latest invoice
  const latestInvoicePaymentIntentStatus = localStorage.getItem(
    'latestInvoicePaymentIntentStatus'
  );
  
  if (latestInvoicePaymentIntentStatus === 'requires_payment_method') {
    const invoiceId = localStorage.getItem('latestInvoiceId');
    const isPaymentRetry = true;
    // create new payment method & retry payment on invoice with new payment method
    createPaymentMethod({
      card,
      isPaymentRetry,
      invoiceId,
    });
  } else {
    // create new payment method & create subscription
    createPaymentMethod({ card });
  }
});
```

I am going to dig through `"https://js.stripe.com/v3/"` to see if I can find an instance of `card`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is `card` declared?

Comment: @aRvi That's his question: where is he supposed to declare it and how does he fill it in? The examples in the documentation don't show how to do it.

Comment: You need to save the user's card in their Customer object. Then you can get the card using the Stripe API.

Comment: @Barmar I'm going to generate a token and use that as the card. Really weird that they didn't include that in the tutorial.

Comment: yeah, since they show how to mount the credit card input field on the page.

Comment: I suggest you write to their tech support, they've always been very helpful to me.

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed a few instructions and the doc certainly didn't help. By `card` I think the stripe doc meant `cardElement` from the other examples.

Here's a step-by-step guide I think which might help you:

First create elements instance. You probably have already done this. Keep this part of code in the global scope for simplicity:

```
var stripe = Stripe('<test-key>');
var elements = stripe.elements();
```

Now, you have stripe `elements`, which is stripe's way of binding your form element to a stripe card element. You probably have a form like this:

```
<body>
  <form id="subscription-form">
    <div id="card-element" class="MyCardElement">
      <!-- Elements will create input elements here -->
    </div>

    <!-- We'll put the error messages in this element -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

The form input id is `card-element`, we will use this input element to be bounded to stripe card. We will do this inside `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function() {

   var cardElement = elements.create("card");

   // This card element is the card that you are looking for 
   cardElement.mount("#card-element");

   
}
```

Over here, the `cardElement` is the `card` instance that you need to pass on form submit. I guess they forgot to rename in this example.

So the code should be something like this, notice I have changed the variable name from `card` to `cardElement`:

```
window.onload = function() {

   var cardElement = elements.create("card");

   // This card element is the card that you are looking for 
   cardElement.mount("#card-element");

   form.addEventListener('submit', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
​
        // If a previous payment was attempted, get the latest invoice
        const latestInvoicePaymentIntentStatus = localStorage.getItem(
           'latestInvoicePaymentIntentStatus'
        );
​
        if (latestInvoicePaymentIntentStatus === 'requires_payment_method') {
           const invoiceId = localStorage.getItem('latestInvoiceId');
           const isPaymentRetry = true;
           // create new payment method & retry payment on invoice with new payment 
           method
            createPaymentMethod({
               cardElement,
               isPaymentRetry,
               invoiceId,
            });
        } else {
           // create new payment method & create subscription
           createPaymentMethod({ cardElement });
        }
    });
}
```

Hopefully this works and the guys at Stripe fix the confusion with their examples.

Comment: Hmm looks like createPaymentMethod takes a card Element object, I'll try this out.

Comment: This is a great answer @ShababbKarim. Just wanted to point out that the docs are based off of this stripe sample: https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/tree/master/fixed-price-subscriptions. And the relevant piece that's missing is here: https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/blob/master/fixed-price-subscriptions/client/vanillajs/script.js#L21-L55.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Variable names starting [Add Elements to your page](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#add-elements-to-your-page) to [Save payment details and create the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#add-elements-to-your-page) don't seem to be consistent, hence OP's confusion.